# How to get info about the file, class and function the code is contained in?

Tags: c++, exception

I am making a command line program. For exception handling, in the throw part, I want the code to display the location where the exception had occurred. For example an exception occurred in, Display.hpp> class display> int Print_Text(); So the throw part of the code should display the location of the exception as explained above. Now, what exactly I want to know is the code that automatically detects what file, class and function the code is located in, and then I can display that to know where an exception occurred.

Comment: Take a look at the predefined preprocessor macros `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`. They won't give you everything you want, but you can at least get the file name and line number.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++20 I'd suggest [std::source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location).

Answer (score 0):

While [possible with `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-line-directive-c-cpp?view=msvc-160), I suggest you don't do that. Such information is not helpful for your users, it's only useful for developers.

Instead, use developer's means like [crash dumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps) (core dumps) and [PDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database) files (symbols) to get the method names, line numbers etc.